# What are the physical limitations of the Bluetooth low energy?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I mean, it probably works the same as standard Bluetooth, so every wall on its way limits the range, but are there any other ones specific to BLE?

Comment: Large data cannot be transferred on BLE..its meant only for notifications or data in small chunks

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any specific limitations to BLE; it is a 2.4 GHz wireless protocol, and is hence damped and reflected in much the same way as any other such protocol: WiFi, Bluetooth Classic or proprietary radio solutions (typically used in wireless keyboard and mice).